# C# adding elements to list in the list (two dimensional list)

Tags: c#, list, exception, generics, dimensional

I have a list:

```
List <List <string>> aList = new List <List <string>> ();
```

I want add something to the list in this list like that:

```
aList [0].Add ("item");
```

But I get `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, why?

Adding list to list works perfect:

```
List <string> testList = new List <string> ();
testList.Add ("item");
aList.Add (testList);
```

Without any bugs.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because the list is empty at first, thus `aList[0]` (getting the first item) isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution to my own question!
I must add any list to my own list before I can do that because it's empty so I can't access the list which not exists.

```
List <string> testList = new List <string> ();
aList.Add (testList);
aList [0].Add ("item");
```

Without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement adding with index assumed that the size of list is >=1 which is not. Just initialization doesn't create a sized list.

Answer (score 0):

```
aList [0].Add ("value");
```

This fails as there is no List at position 0 to add your value to.

Try

```
aList [0] = new List<string>;
aList [0].Add ("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Row
{
    public  List<string> Elements { get; private set; }

    public Row()
    {
        Elements = new List<string>();
    }

    public Row(List<string> elements)
    {
        Elements = elements;
    }
}
```

Using :

```
List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();
        rows.Add(new Row( new List<string>(){"abc","abc","abc"}));
        rows.Add(new Row(new List<string>() { "xyz", "xyz", "xyz" }));
```

or

```
 Row row = new Row();
        row.Elements.Add("abc");
        row.Elements.Add("xyz");

       rows.Add(row);
```

You can not add elements to a list which is not instateated